# Custom UITableViewCell resize label when setEditing is called

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Okay here is a picture:

[image]

I've got custom UITableViewCell with UILabel.

It's obvious I should resize my custom UILabel in -setEditing method, but how to exactly calculate how much to resize it? And is there efficient way to resize reused cells?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything in `setEditing` method if you have the right autoresizing mask:

```
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: That's a nice little tutorial from you. Thank you!

Comment: yeah, just try it, it works. If you specify your cell in the nib file than you can set autoresizing there, but all you have to do is to make right bound flexible

Answer (score 0):

So the first question is how are you adding the label to the `UITableViewCell`? If you are adding it to the cell's `view`, then that is where your problem begins.

`UITableViewCell`s have a `contentView` property. This `contentView` is responsible for resizing its contents when the cell enters editing mode. It knows how to do this. The cell's `view` property does not. So, first you need to add your `UILabel` as a subview of the cell's `contentView` in `initWithStyle:`. The cell doesn't actually know how big it is in `initWithStyle:`, though, so you can set the frame of the label in `layoutSubviews`.

As for resizing the cell, you can do this in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

In this method, you can check the `indexPath` of the row and configure the height appropriately.